# How to open files which are located in VirtualBox's Guest Machine from Netbeans of Host Machine

Tags: virtualbox, netbeans

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed in my Host Machine and it has VirtualBox. I have Guest Machine wich runs Ubuntu 10.10.

I have NetBeans installed in Host Machine and need to open my project files which are located in Guest Machine. The reason I need it is because in my working place I have not access to install any applications, that is why I have Guest Machine where I have Web Server installed on it and also I have one web application that I am developing.

I need to open that web application files from Guest Machine's Netbeans in order to modify/create new files for my web application.

I have configured SSH server of Guest Machine and added port redirection in the VirtualBox so that now I can connect to it from Host Machine. But I could not find any way to open those files from Netbeans.

Could anybody give me advice about how can I do that please?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to say that I don't want to use SharedFolders.

Answer (score 1):

There's a much easier way. Just store your project in a shared folder. Set up shared folders using [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders) and keep your source code there. Now you can access the files in Ubuntu using any method you want.

Answer (score 0):

try looking into `shared folders` in vbox. It would basically allow you to share files without the need for samba/ssh/ftp.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand if right ssh is working

You can navigate to any folder in the Guest Machine with Nautilus (press CTRL+L and type *ssh:/ip/folder/folder* in the address bar) or connect to it selecting "*Connect to server*" from the file menu.

After doing that the remote filesystem will be mounted under ~/.gvfs. You should be able to open any file from there from any program that can access the local filesystem.

Comment: You are right. I have configured SSH and now I can connect to Guest Machine through SSH and list files in Nautilus. But didn't find any way to open those files in NetBeans. 
In addition ~/.gvfs is empty in my case? What should it contain?

Comment: It should contain a directory called "sftp in x.x.x.x" where x.x.x.x is the IP of the host machine. If you can browse your files from Nautilus, it must had mounted the filesystem somewhere.

Comment: Are you using nautilus as root?

Comment: I don't have root access in the Host Machine. That is the MAIN reason I am complicating my work. I can neither install any application nor I am sudoer user.

Comment: If you type mount in a terminal, is gvfs-fuse-daemon in the mounted filesystems list?

Comment: No, there is no any entry saying gvfs-fuse-daemon.

Comment: sftp://bakhtiyor@127.0.0.1:2222/var/www - it is the path that I see if I see the property of the file in Nautilus by right clicking by mouse on the file and selecting Properties command.

Comment: Then gvfs is not installed and you can't install it :(. I'm sorry but that means this is a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

- go to your netbeans project and click on "properties"
- go to "Run configuration" and fill in all your project + virtualbox details
- make sure when you press "test connection", you get a message saying "connection succeeded"
- now, go to your virtualbox terminal and make sure you change ownership permissions for that folder to include your username..... use the following command:

sudo chown -R your-username:current-folder-owner /path/to/project/root

- you should be able to save remotely to your virtualbox at this point :)